# Can not find module by Lazy loading in angular2 es5

Tags: lazy-loading, angular2-routing, ecmascript-5

I am wirting an app with Angular 2 in EcmaScript 5. By Implementing of "Lazy Loading" I get this error message:

Can not find 'DetailModule'.

That are my /src/app/app.module.js

```
var ngCore = require('@angular/core'),
    platformBrowser = require('@angular/platform-browser'),
    router = require('@angular/router');

var AppComponent = require('my-app/app/app.component.js');
var ListComponent = require('my-app/list/list.component.js');

var appRoutes = [
  { path: '', component: ListComponent },
  { path: 'detail', loadChildren: "detail/detail.module.js#DetailModule"}
];

MyAppModule = ngCore.NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    platformBrowser.BrowserModule,      
    router.RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ListComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
}).Class({
  constructor: function (){
  }
});

module.exports = MyAppModule;
```

This is my detail.module.js:

```
var ngCore = require('@angular/core'),
    router = require('@angular/router');

var ListComponent = require('my-app/list/list.component.js'),
    DetailComponent = require('my-app/detail/detail.component.js');

var routes = [
  { path: '', component: DetailComponent }
];

var routing = router.RouterModule.forChild(routes);

var module = ngCore.NgModule({
  imports: [ routing ],
  declarations: [ DetailComponent, ListComponent ]
}).Class({
  constructor: function (){
  }
});

module.exports = {
  DetailModule: module
};
```

How I to export the module with ES5, so that angular2 detect is?